# Microsoft Graph: List of possible modifiedProperty values

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The descriptions of the property **modifiedProperty** do not contain a list of (or a link to) its possible values, which makes it difficult to utilize APIs that return this resource type.

**Document Details**

- Content: modifiedProperty resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0
- Content Source: api-reference/v1.0/resources/modifiedproperty.md
- Product: microsoft-identity-platform
- Technology: microsoft-graph
- Link : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/modifiedproperty.md

It would be helpful if the list of possible values could be provided.

Comment: Please let us know which API you are looking for?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm trying to utilize List directoryAudits endpoint. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt you're going to be able to find such a list. The values of the `modifiedProperty` property are going to vary based on which type of Azure resource you're looking at and which property on that resource was modified. The only thing you can be certain of is that the `modifiedProperty` will be empty or it will contain a property name, the old value, and the new value, according to the documentation you linked.

If you are trying to code for a particular type of Azure resource or a particular type of property, you should look into the documentation for that resource or property instead of the documentation for getting that information.